# How extract xml variable value from all HTTP response in Jmeter in one file

Tags: jmeter

I'm using for Jmeter for performance testing. In which I'm sending 100s of http requests and server is sending response in xml format.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lpr><transactionId>31475976053976540</transactionId></lpr>
```

I want to store all the transactionIds of all responses into one single file. How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use JMeter's Listener configuration.

First of all extract your TransactionID using a regular expression 
Use the following info to extract transaction ID

```
Name of Created Variable : transactionId
Regular Expression : <transactionId>(\d*)<\/transactionId>
Template : $1$
Match no: 1
```

JMeter allows you to save the above variable by configuring `user.properties` file.

Open your User.properties file and add the following line and save it .

```
sample_variables=transactionId
```

Restart Jmeter to pick new changes made in properties file.
Add a View Results tree listener and uncheck all options in sample save configuration so that jmeter wont save any data except transactionIds

[image]

Give file path to the results tree listener and run the test.

You will get all transaction IDs in the file.

Please let me know if it helps.

More info :

[Regular expressions](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)